# Show ProgressBar until GridLayout is displayed

Tags: android, xml, grid-layout

Is there a solution to show a progressbar(cyclic) until a .xml file that contains a gridlayout is dispalyed ?I tried to find this in other questions, but I didn't find something like this. Thanks!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="ScrollViewCount">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="19"
        android:columnCount="2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/teacher1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/woman"
                android:contentDescription="@string/woman" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/phdr_ludmila_b_l_kov"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/josefin"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/kabinet_105_kolka"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/vyu_ovan_p_edm_ty"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/ludmila_belikova_oavm_cz"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/_420_571_755_504"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/konzulta_n_hodiny"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/josefin"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pond_l_7_00_7_30"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/teacher2"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/woman"
                android:contentDescription="@string/woman" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/mgr_jana_blinkov"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/josefin"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/kabinet_151_kolka"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/vyu_ovan_p_edm_ty"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/jana_blinkova_oavm_cz"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/_420_571_755_526"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/konzulta_n_hodiny"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/josefin"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tvrtek_7_00_7_30"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
                android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/teacher3"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/woman"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/woman" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/rndr_eva_tver_kov"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/josefin"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/kabinet_243_hlavn_budova"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/vyu_ovan_p_edm_ty"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/eva_ctverackova_oavm_cz"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/_420_571_755_513"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/konzulta_n_hodiny"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/josefin"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/pond_l_15_15_16_00"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/teacher4"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/woman"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/woman" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/mgr_jitka_g_brl_kov"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/josefin"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/kabinet_255_hlavn_budova"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/vyu_ovan_p_edm_ty"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/jitka_gabrlikova_oavm_cz"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/_420_571_755_515"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/konzulta_n_hodiny"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/josefin"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/st_eda_7_00_7_30"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/caviar"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```html
package com.app.clupascu.oavm;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.Objects;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private CardView teacher1;
    private CardView teacher2;
    private CardView teacher3;
    private CardView teacher4;


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        teacher1 = (CardView)  vw.findViewById(R.id.teacher1);
        teacher2 = (CardView)  vw.findViewById(R.id.teacher2);
        teacher3 = (CardView)  vw.findViewById(R.id.teacher3);
        teacher4 = (CardView)  vw.findViewById(R.id.teacher4);

        teacher1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ludmila_belikova);
                ImageButton dialogButton = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.clButton);
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        teacher2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.jana_blinkova);
                ImageButton dialogButton = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.clButton);
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        teacher3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.eva_ctverackova);
                ImageButton dialogButton = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.clButton);
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        teacher4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.jitka_garlikova);
                ImageButton dialogButton = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.clButton);
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        return vw;

    }
}
```

**EDIT** I added .xml and .java files. 
So, I have 4 CardViews and I want, if it is possible, to show a progressbar(cyclic) until a .xml file that contains a gridlayout is dispalyed.

Comment: Are you using Glide library to load images into grid view ?

Comment: No, I have some CardViews in GridLayout

Comment: post your code for xml.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create progress bar in your xml file.

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
```

use **setVisibility** in your activity or fragment.

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

after you should call the gridView method.

then setVisibility gone. like this.

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

*progressbar visible until gridlayout is dispalyed.*

Comment: In GridLayout I inserted a lot od CardViews and in my fragment file I called only CardView method onClick, i didn't call the gridView method.

Comment: I added @Gayathri .

Comment: I haven't added the progressbar yet. I asked if it is possible to do this.